# widening/narrowing with org-goto

Tags: org-mode, navigation, narrowing

`org-goto` (as well as `orgnav`, `helm-org-rifle`) strictly respects narrowing. is there a way to have it disregard it, making it possible to jump to places in the file *outside* current narrowing? or is there another way to jump around this way?

i would like to use it jump somewhere anywhere in the present file, paste or copy something, then return to where i was working.

i currently use `org-goto` with path completion, and in the completion minibuffer, *all* headings from the current file are shown, not just those in the narrowed buffer. so it gives you the impression that it will move to any heading in the file, but then it fails to take you anywhere if you select a heading outside the present narrowed buffer.

but perhaps there's another way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this narrowing that you initiate interactively, e.g. with `C-x n n`, or is it narrowing done by some code (e.g. automatically)? If the former, just don't narrow, or unbind the narrowing keys. If the latter, maybe advise the relevant narrowing function, to check whether you're in Org mode or whatever, and make it a no-op in that case.

Comment: it's the former. i work on a narrowed buffer with my proper text in it. i have to narrow otherwise emacs is too slow. i would like to be able to cull some unneeded text, but move it under a different heading in the same file so it isn't lost. i'd have thought that moving between two headings in the same file without widening would be an existing functionality, but maybe what i'm after doesnt really exist.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need it for [this issue](https://github.com/takaxp/org-tree-slide/issues/58).